# Finding Latest First x among consecutive x from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query to find first latest 1's from each group as below. For example, for Group 1, It shouldn't be 1/2/2022 since it has 1/6/2022 which was shown later. Shouldn't be 1/7/2022 too for Group 1.

Please let me know if you have any idea.

Thanks!

```
Table x (AsOfDate, Group_Id, Value)
AsOfDate   Group_Id   Value  
1/1/2022   1          0
1/1/2022   2          1
1/2/2022   1          1
1/2/2022   2          1
1/3/2022   1          0
1/3/2022   2          0
1/4/2022   1          0
1/4/2022   2          0
1/5/2022   1          0
1/5/2022   2          1
1/6/2022   1          1
1/6/2022   2          0
1/7/2022   1          1
1/7/2022   2          0

Output
AsOfDate   Group_Id
1/6/2022   1   
1/5/2022   2
```

Comment: "Shouldn't be 1/7/2022 too for Group 1." - um, why? That is the latest?

Comment: Latest "First" 1 among consecutive 1s!

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make sense (to me anyway)

Comment: It would make sense if you read below answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is find the earliest date of the last group for continuous row with `Value = 1`

Use `LAG()` window function to find the continuous group of `Value`

use `dense_rank()` to rank it by `grp` find the latest group (`r = 1`)

`min()` to get the "first" `AsOfDate`

```
select AsOfDate = min(AsOfDate),
       Group_Id
from
(
    select *, r = dense_rank() over (partition by Group_Id, Value 
                                         order by grp desc)
    from
    (
        select *, grp = sum(g) over (partition by Group_Id order by AsOfDate)
        from
        (
            select *, g = case when Value <> lag(Value) over (partition by Group_Id 
                                                                  order by AsOfDate)
                               then 1
                               else 0
                               end
            from   x
        ) x
    ) x
) x
where Value = 1
and   r     = 1
group by Group_Id
```